# Max-min inequality

Tags: calculus, functions, optimization

It is known that 
$\underset{x}{\max} \underset{y}{\min} f(x,y) \leq \underset{y}{\min}  \underset{x}{\max} f(x,y)$ . 
When does equality hold in this expression?

Answer (score 1):

Let $\max_x \min_y f(x, y) = \max_x g(x) = g(a)$ and $\min_y \max_x f(x, y) = \min_y h(y) = h(b)$.  We have
$$\max_x \min_y f(x, y)= g(a) \le f(a, b) \le h(b) = \min_y \max_x f(x, y)$$

So for equality, we need an element $(a, b)$ to exist s.t. $\min_y f(a, y) = f(a, b) = \max_x f(x, b)$.

Answer (score 1):

The inequality is the "weak duality inequality" and when it is equality it is called strong duality equality, see [this](http://web.stanford.edu/class/ee364a/lectures/duality.pdf) for more detail.

The strong duality holds for **convex functions** (which their domain has non-empty interior)

Answer (score 1):

Equality holds if *$f(w,z)$* is convex in *w* and concave in *$z$* (or convex in *$z$* and concave in *$w$*)